# jQuery UI datetimepicker option sliderAccess not Showing buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

i'm using the [datetime picker plugin](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/), when i use the option to show

<kbd>+</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> buttons next to the slider it doesn't work i don't know why

[image]

*Notice*

- i'm trying to show this on a desktop browser
- my console doesn't show any errors

i'm using this given code from the plugin web site

```
 $('#slider_example_3').datetimepicker({
    addSliderAccess: true,
    sliderAccessArgs: { touchonly: false }
 });
```

[jsFiddle to show the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/qe8XV/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is not working because you must include an additional script `jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js`

I can't find any indication in the docs, but I found it be checking the examples on the site.

Script here: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/6FGgA/